# Error with SQLite when trying to run a unit test on simple calculation

Tags: c#, unit-testing

So I am trying to create a unit test class for a simple calculation method that simply adds 5 values together and returns the sum. It is used to calculate a total train fare cost for customers booking onto logical trains.

But when I run the test I get an error telling me this:

[image: Error about SQLite]

Does anyone know why it is saying this? It is completely oblivious to me what this means.

Here is the test method I have set up:

```cs
namespace FareTest
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        //Test method for testing if the fare cost value comes out as expected
        [TestMethod()]
        public void TestFare()
        {
            //Reference customer fare calculator
            Customers fare = new Customers();

            //Expected value of test
            int expected = 80;

            //The value that comes out of the calculation
            int actual;

            //Variables to add up in the test calculation
            int totalCost = 0;
            int travelFare = 50;
            int firstClass = 10;
            int sleeper = 10;
            int cabin = 10;

            //Test the method and store the value returned in an integer for checking if it is as expected
            actual = fare.CalculateFare(totalCost, travelFare, firstClass, sleeper, cabin);

            //Check the value returned from the calculation against the expected value

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
    }
}
```

The class that uses the method for calculation is as follows:

```cs
//Create sql connection variable with the path name of the database required
private SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=F:\Uni\OOP\Assessment 2\Trains.db;Version=3;Journal Mode=Off;");

//Create new customer object to hole each customers specific details
private CustomerDecorator cust = new CustomerDecorator();

//Decorator for adding First Class attribute to booking
private FirstClassDecorator firstClassDecorator = new FirstClassDecorator();

//Decorator for adding cabin attribute to booking
private CabinDecorator cabinDecorator = new CabinDecorator();

//Integer variables for holding prices
private int totalCost = new int();
private int travelFare = new int ();
private int firstClass = new int();
private int sleeper = new int();
private int cabin = new int();

private void btnMakeBook_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    try
    {
        //If no details have been entered
        if (txtCustName.Text == "" && txtCustTrainID.Text == "" && cbxCustDepart.Text == "" && cbxCustArrive.Text == "" && cbxCustCoach.Text == "" &&
            txtCustSeat.Text == "")
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        //If the character in train ID is not a capital
        if (Regex.IsMatch(txtCustTrainID.Text, "[a-z]"))
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        //sql command variables for validating data
        #region SQL command variables

        //Create sql command variable to create new command for searching if train has cabins for sleeping
        SQLiteCommand chkCabin = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT sleeperBerth FROM Train WHERE sleeperBerth = 1 AND id = @custTID", con);
        chkCabin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custTID", txtCustTrainID.Text);

        //Create sql command variable to check if the train selected is a sleeper
        SQLiteCommand chkSleeper = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT sleeperBerth FROM Train WHERE sleeperBerth = 1 AND id = @CustTrain", con);
        chkSleeper.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustTrain", txtCustTrainID.Text);

        //Create sql command variable to create new command for searching if train has cabins for sleeping
        SQLiteCommand chkFirst = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Train WHERE firstClass = 1 AND id = @custTRAINID", con);
        chkFirst.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custTRAINID", txtCustTrainID.Text);

        //Create sql command variable for checking seat number booked
        SQLiteCommand chkSeat = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Bookings WHERE coach= @Coach AND seat = @Seat AND trainID = @custTid", con);
        chkSeat.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Coach", cbxCustCoach.Text);
        chkSeat.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Seat", txtCustSeat.Text);
        chkSeat.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custTid", txtCustTrainID.Text);

        //Create sql command for checking if departing station selected is not where this train leaves from
        SQLiteCommand chkDepartIsNotDest = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Train WHERE departure = @departing AND id = @Tid", con);
        chkDepartIsNotDest.Parameters.AddWithValue("@departing", cbxCustDepart.Text);
        chkDepartIsNotDest.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tid", txtCustTrainID.Text);

        //Create sql command variable to create new command for checking if depart station exists on the train trying to be booked
        SQLiteCommand chkDepart = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Train WHERE departure LIKE @depart OR destination LIKE @depart OR intermediate LIKE @depart AND id = @tID", con);
        chkDepart.Parameters.AddWithValue("@depart", "%" + cbxCustDepart.Text + "%");
        chkDepart.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tID", txtCustTrainID.Text);

        //Create sql command variable to create new command for checking if arrive station exists on the train trying to be booked
        SQLiteCommand chkArrive = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Train WHERE departure LIKE @arrive OR destination LIKE @arrive OR intermediate LIKE @arrive AND id = @cTID", con);
        chkArrive.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arrive", "%" + cbxCustArrive.Text + "%");
        chkArrive.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cTID", txtCustTrainID.Text);

        //Create new command variable for checking order of stops
        SQLiteCommand chkStops = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT intermediate, departure, destination FROM Train WHERE id = @train", con);
        chkStops.Parameters.AddWithValue("@train", txtCustTrainID.Text);

        //Create sql command variable to create new command for searching train id
        SQLiteCommand chkTrain = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT id FROM Train WHERE id = @custtID", con);
        chkTrain.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custtID", txtCustTrainID.Text);

        #endregion

        #region arrange list of stops in order

        //Close connection. This is here as I was getting strange exceptions saying the connection was still open when trying to validate specific things one after another
        con.Close();

        //Start the connection
        con.Open();

        //Create a new data table to hold a list of the trains temporarily
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        //Execute the command and store the data in the datatable created
        dt.Load(chkStops.ExecuteReader());

        con.Close();


        //String to hold Intermediate stop value obtained from database
        string interStops = dt.Rows[0]["intermediate"].ToString();
        //String to hold depart station value obtained from database
        string depart = dt.Rows[0]["departure"].ToString();
        //String to hold arrive station value obtained from database
        string arrive = dt.Rows[0]["destination"].ToString();

        //split the string value from intermediate obtained from the database into seperate strings and store them in a string array called stops
        string[] stops = interStops.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        //Set size of array to 4 if there are not 4 intermediate stops with the specific train
        Array.Resize(ref stops, 4);

        //String array to hold all the possible stops, including adding null if it does not stop at specific intermediate stops
        string[] allStops = new string[6];

        //Set the correct direction order for the stops
        allStops[0] = depart;
        allStops[1] = stops[0];
        allStops[2] = stops[1];
        allStops[3] = stops[2];
        allStops[4] = stops[3];
        allStops[5] = arrive;
        #endregion

        try
        {
            //Stores the details of the textboxes/Combo boxes into the customer details for each customer object
            #region variable assigning

            cust.TrainID = txtCustTrainID.Text;
            cust.Name = txtCustName.Text;
            cust.DepStation = cbxCustDepart.Text;
            cust.ArriveStation = cbxCustArrive.Text;
            cust.Coach = cbxCustCoach.Text;                    
            cust.Seat = Convert.ToInt32(txtCustSeat.Text);

            //Set the component the first class decorator will decorate
            firstClassDecorator.SetComponent(cust);

            //Set the component the cabin decorator will decorate
            cabinDecorator.SetComponent(cust);

            //If first class check box is checked, sets first class to true, else false
            if (chbCustFirst.IsChecked == true)
            {
                //Use decorator to decorate booking with first class
                firstClassDecorator.FirstClass = true;
            }
            else
            {
                firstClassDecorator.FirstClass = false;
            }
            //If cabin check box is checked, sets cabin to true, else false
            if (chbCustCabin.IsChecked == true)
            {
                //Use decorator to decorate booking with first cabin
                cabinDecorator.Cabin = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cabinDecorator.Cabin = false;
            }

            #endregion

            //Set cost variable values
            #region Set cost variable values

            //If customer is traveling the full distance, set travel fare to £50, else £25
            if (cbxCustDepart.Text == "Edinburgh (Waverley)" && cbxCustArrive.Text == "London (Kings Cross)" ||
                cbxCustDepart.Text == "London (Kings Cross)" && cbxCustArrive.Text == "Edinburgh (Waverley)")
            {
                travelFare = 50;
            }
            else
            {
                travelFare = 25;
            }

            //If the train selected is a sleeper, set sleeper value to 10, else nothing
            if (chkSleeper.ExecuteScalar() != null)
            {
                sleeper = 10;
            }
            else
            {
                sleeper = 0;
            }

            //If cabin checkbox is checked, set cabin value to 10, else nothing
            if (chbCustCabin.IsChecked == true)
            {
                cabin = 10;
            }
            else
            {
                cabin = 0;
            }

            //If first class checkbox is selected, set first class value to 10, else nothing
            if (chbCustFirst.IsChecked == true)
            {
                firstClass = 10;
            }
            else
            {
                firstClass = 0;
            }                    

            #endregion

            //Show messagebox that lists all the surcharges and the total cost of all together
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("The total cost for your fare is as follows:" +
                                                      "\nTravel Fare: £" + travelFare +
                                                      "\nFirst Class: £" + firstClass +
                                                      "\nSleeper: £" + sleeper +
                                                      "\nCabin: £" + cabin +
                                                      "\nTotal Fare Cost: £" + CalculateFare(totalCost, travelFare, firstClass, sleeper, cabin) +
                                                      "\n\nDo you want to confirm this booking?",
                                                      "Fare Cost",
                                                      MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                                                      MessageBoxImage.Question);
            //If the user confirms the booking, adds them to the database
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                //Sequence to create new booking
            }

            //Else resets entry and returns
            else
            {
                //Clears all textboxes, combo boxes and check boxes back to default
                txtCustName.Clear();
                txtCustTrainID.Clear();
                cbxCustDepart.SelectedIndex = -1;
                cbxCustArrive.SelectedIndex = -1;
                cbxCustCoach.SelectedIndex = -1;
                txtCustSeat.Clear();
                chbCustCabin.IsChecked = false;
                chbCustFirst.IsChecked = false;

                return;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //Display errors after throwing exceptions
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //If no details have been entered
        if (txtCustName.Text == "" || txtCustTrainID.Text == "" || cbxCustDepart.Text == "" || cbxCustArrive.Text == "" || cbxCustCoach.Text == "" ||
            txtCustSeat.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have left some fields blank!");

            return;
        }

        //If the character in train ID is not a capital
        if (Regex.IsMatch(txtCustTrainID.Text, "[a-z]"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must make the letter in the train ID a capital.");

            //Resets train id textbox
            txtCustTrainID.Clear();

            return;
        }
    }
}

public int CalculateFare(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
{
    //Add prices together and return the value
    a = b + c + d + e;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Does the Customers class calls DB? Can you provider it's implementation as well, please?

Comment: It does yes, there is too much code in there for me to add it to this post though, I will edit it with just the sections that uses the calculate fare

Comment: is ur sqlite interop dll in the folder?

Comment: @ Mark Ng, I'm unsure, I just started using SQLite the other day, It allows me to do select, insert, update statements in the actual program... so i'll say... I guess so? But I am unsure where it would need to be in the first place to be honest?

Comment: @Dimitar I have edited to show the most code I can

Comment: You need to add reference to SqlLite to the test project

Comment: When I try to add a reference to SQLite to the test project, it doesn't show up in the list of references?

Comment: got it working, needed to download it through the nuget packages. Thanks for the advice!